# Jenkins Persistent Editable Global Variable

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, tagging, continuous-deployment

I'm looking for a plugin/approach that lets me set and read a persistent global variable for use between jobs.

The scenario is that I have CI job that runs tests on various branches of the codebase and I want to associate a build number that corresponds to the last stable build of the release branch. i.e.

```
Build No    Branch    Result    GolbalSharedThingVal    
5           release   Success   1.5
6           dev       Fail      1.5
7           dev       Success   1.7
8           release   Unstable  1.7
9           release   Success   1.9
10          release   Fail      1.9
```

Then in my deployment job I want to annotate the build with the version using a groovy post build action:

```
manager.addShortText(" ${manager.build.env.get('GolbalSharedThingVal')}")
```

Does anyone have any advice about what GolbalSharedThingVal could be?

Many Thanks,
Vackar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin is **the** plugin for anything related to environment variables.

Don't know about setting a persistent global variable (that goes against the design principles of Jenkins), but you could have the job export a value to a properties file, and other jobs read the value from the properties file at initialization and expose it as environment variable to other build steps.

Of course the property file would have to be centrally located on Jenkins master somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that the different jobs/stages run on the same agent, you can use a file as a persistent storage. In a *declarative pipeline* this could look like

```yaml
stage('myStage') {                                             
  steps {                                                         
    echo 'in myStage'                                          
    sh '''                                                        
      # get value from file into environment variable
      export PERSISTENTVAR=`cat $HOME/persistent_var_file`                        
      
      # do some stuff here to e.g. change $PERSISTENTVAR

      # save env variable into file for later use
      echo $PERSISTENTVAR > $HOME/persistent_var_file                             
    '''                                                           
  }
}
```